# displaying a value from local storage

Tags: local-storage, sencha-touch-2

I have certain data saved in the local storage. The same has been saved onto the store. What I require is to extract a particular item from the localstorage and display it. I am not sure how to do that.

For eg:

```
model.data.servname = servname;
model.data.port = port;
model.data.protocol = protocol;
model.data.username = username;
model.data.password = password;
model.data.domain = domain;
model.data.apptitle = apptitle;
model.data.appconfig = appconfig;
model.save();

var store = Ext.getStore('configStore'); // Get the store
store.add({servname : 'infoimage'}); // Add an instance of you model item
store.sync(); // Will add the item to the locastorage
var item = store.getAt(0);
```

this part of my code saves the data onto the local storage and the store. Now, in my main controller:

```
init : function() {
  if (!this.landingoverlay) {
    this.landingoverlay = Ext.Viewport.add({
      xtype : 'landingPageOverlay'
    });
  }
  this.landingoverlay.show();
}
```

I want to display the apptitle value.

but

```
console.log(Ext.getCmp('apptitle').getValue());
```

does not work cause its not yet defined. But the value is there in the local storage. How do i access that value and display it here?

Comment: if your `configStore` is configured to use a `localstorage` proxy, then you just have to call `Ext.getStore('configStore').load()`. It will copy the data from `localstorage` to your `configStore`. You can check it out by `console.log` your Store data

Comment: ok. the I got the store loaded. console.log(Ext.getStore('configStore').load());
      var a = Ext.getCmp('apptitle').getValue();
      console.log(Ext.getCmp('apptitle').getValue()); but that doesn seem to be working. How do I extract a particular data from the store and display it?

Comment: no... `Ext.getStore().load()` is a function, logging it is meaningless ... just `console.log((Ext.getStore('configStore'))`. It will return an object, you can inspect the `data` attribute to see if your data is fully loaded from `localstorage` or not

Comment: well, i have inspected that and i know that the data is fully loaded. My question is, how do i extract a particular data from the store and print it?

Comment: ok to this point your question is figured out, please check my answer in a few minutes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get data from your store which is configured to use a `localstorage` proxy:

```
`Ext.getStore('configStore').load()`
```

To iterate through your Store instances and print them:

```
var store = Ext.getStore('configStore').
store.each(function(record){
  console.log(record.get('the_name_of_field_you_want'));
});
```

Hope this helps.